# Knockout-Validation - data-bind observable array

Tags: validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm trying to do some validation for groups of radio buttons, where each group needs to have a value selected. I'm attempting to use [Knockout-Validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) to do the validation, but I'm having trouble making this dynamic. I can set up the validation, but getting it to validate each group individually is a challenge. Right now it's treating all groups of questions the same. I have an [example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LG85B/) which shows the current situation.

I create the questions dynamically in the back end from a DB, but I could potentially add in a unique identifier for each question, but how do I reference an observable who's name I can't know ahead of time for a number of questions I can't predetermine the number of?

Example code form JSFiddle:

```
$(function() {
var viewModelQuestionnaire = ko.validatedObservable({
    'checkScore': ko.observable().extend({
        required: true
    }),
    submit: function () {
        if (this.isValid()) {
            alert('Thank you.');
        } else {
            console.log(this);
            alert('Please check your submission.');
            this.errors.showAllMessages();
        }
    }
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModelQuestionnaire);
```

});

```
<form action="/Questionnaire/Save" method="post">    <table id="ESAS-questions">
        <tr class="esas-question-row">
            <td class="esas-best-area">
                <div class="esas-best-symptom">No Pain</div>
            </td>
            <td class="esas-score-area">
                    <span class="esas-score">0<input type="radio" name="question_id-1" value="0" data-bind="checked: checkScore"/></span>
                    <span class="esas-score">1<input type="radio" name="question_id-1" value="1" data-bind="checked: checkScore"/></span>
                    <span class="esas-score">2<input type="radio" name="question_id-1" value="2" data-bind="checked: checkScore"/></span></td>
            <td class="esas-worst-area">
                <span class="esas-worst-symptom">Worst Possible Pain</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="esas-question-row">
            <td class="esas-best-area">
                <div class="esas-best-symptom">No Tiredness</div>
                    <div class="esas-best-subtext">(Tiredness = lack of energy)</div>
            </td>
            <td class="esas-score-area">
                    <span class="esas-score">0<input type="radio" name="question_id-2" value="0" data-bind="checked: checkScore"/></span>
                    <span class="esas-score">1<input type="radio" name="question_id-2" value="1" data-bind="checked: checkScore"/></span>
                    <span class="esas-score">2<input type="radio" name="question_id-2" value="2" data-bind="checked: checkScore"/></span> </td>
            <td class="esas-worst-area">
                <span class="esas-worst-symptom">Worst Possible Tiredness</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="finish" data-bind="click:submit" /></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid multiple error message for that you have to customize the display of your objects validation message by using validationMessage binding and stop the default error message insertion with knockout validation options.

```
data-bind="validationOptions: { insertMessages: false }"  //default validation will not insert  


 // customize the display of your objects validation message
 <p class="invalid" data-bind="validationMessage: checkScore"></p>
```

You have binded same property to both question so whenever one field is selected it select other one also.You can have list of questions as array of objects in observableArray.

Sample structure for list of questions:-

```
var questions=[
  {
    question: "No Pain",
    checkScore: ko.observable().extend({
       required: true
    }),
    description: "Worst Possible Pain"
  },
  {
    question: "No Tiredness (Tiredness = lack of energy)",
    checkScore: ko.observable().extend({
      required: true
    }),
    description: "Worst Possible Tiredness"
  }
]
```

But for questionList validation you have to enable deep(recursive) validation.

[***Fiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/LG85B/2/)

Comment: Thanks, I was going to ask about the multiple validation messages next. But my question was really about binded the property to each question individually. What's the best way to go about that?

Comment: observableArray is the best option